# Graph added to UIView in table cell behaves strange when scrolling table

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am having an issue with my app that has me stumped. I have a dynamic prototype UITableview and the cell has a UIView in it which I use a frame for adding a line graph.

This code is called from cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
UIView *graphWindow=(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:5000];

CKSparkline *sparkline = [[CKSparkline alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, graphWindow.frame.size.width, graphWindow.frame.size.height)];

sparkline.data = item.dataPoints;
sparkline.lineColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
sparkline.drawArea=YES;
sparkline.drawPoints=YES;

[graphWindow addSubview:sparkline];
```

At first the graphs all appear fine. See image below
[image]

But when I scroll to the bottom, the bottom cell has somehow combined the first cell and last cell's graphs together.
[image]

When I scroll back up to the top, the top cell seems to have done the same thing.
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: when you scroll tableview it automatically calls cellForRowIndexPath that's the reason it automatically changes the position of the graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you don't reset the graph when setting up a new cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Based on your images above, I would be willing to be you have exactly 6 cells total, right?

If that's true, then the last cell overwrites the graph, which is just the first cell's graph. That way, both cells appear to have the same information in their graphs. This is true because both are referencing the same graph in-memory!

I think the answer is that you need to add a little bit of code to clear your graph each time you go to write new information to it. Can you post a little bit of the "graph drawing" code? I bet we can find the answer in there! It might be as simple as clearing the context of the `UIView` in `drawRect:` (assuming the graph is a subclass of `UIView` implementing its own drawing).

---

***EDIT:***

Just re-read your post. The issue isn't what I described above, although I'm leaving it there because it will help once you fix your issue.

Your issue is that you're creating a new `UIView` (`CKSparkline`) in EVERY call to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is problematic, because your cells get recycled. So, the REAL problem is that you end up with a cell that has 2 `CKSparkline` views added. If you had a large number of cells, you would end up with multiple of these layered on top of one another. You need to figure out a way to have each cell have one `CKSparkline` view and just re-configure it each time you have a call to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I would add the `CKSparkline` as a subview of your cell and then re-configure it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Basically, a simple rule of thumb is **never create new views in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.** Ideally, you just would use a basic form of this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"item" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureForItem:self.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Then, with a `CKSparkline` property in the cell, you can re-configure the sparkline graph in the cell as needed and you don't worry about creating new views in your tableview.

Comment: This is very useful. Let me experiment and I will get back to you. This has certainly helped frame the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Hey...i fixed this by making the UIView in Storyboards of class CKSparkLine...and then just updating the datapoint property per cell. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness Glad to help! Was it helpful enough for an upvote? ;-)

Comment: It was...and I did :-)